# Making plane parallel to $xy$ axis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, projective-geometry, projection

I want to rotate plane: $2x + 4y + 2z + 4 = 0$ to make it parallel to $xy$ axis by using rotation matrix. In specific, how to calculate angles of rotation? I can't find any good explanation on the web, so if anyone knows how to do it, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Essentially, you’re trying to rotate the plane’s normal vector so that it parallels the $z$-axis. There is an infinite number of rotations that will do this. Are there any other properties that you want this rotation to have? Do you want to rotate about the origin or some other point?

Comment: Does it even have to be a rotation? It’s quite easy to construct a reflection that will also perform this alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your plane has normal vector $(2,4,2)$ as read from the coefficients of the equation. You want to rotate that to some multiple of $(0,0,1)$.

> how to calculate angles of rotation

You can use the fact that the inner product (dot product) is proportional to the cosine of the angle between the vectors:

$$\langle v,w\rangle=\lVert v\rVert\cdot\lVert w\rVert\cdot\cos\theta$$

which you can rearrange to

$$\theta=\arccos\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\lVert v\rVert\cdot\lVert w\rVert}$$

giving you an angle in the range $0°\le\theta\le180°$ as expected. In your case:

$$\theta=\arccos\frac{\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle}{\left\lVert\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\2\end{pmatrix}\right\rVert\cdot\left\lVert\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\rVert}=\arccos\frac{2}{\sqrt{24}\cdot1}=\arccos\frac1{\sqrt6}$$

Usually you'd need to combine this rotation angle with a definition of the axis of rotation. That axis direction would be orthogonal to both the vectors I gave, so you can use the cross product of these vectors to compute the axis.